# Cant put id to div from variable Jade

Tags: html, node.js, express, pug

I have the following in my Jade view:

```
- var items = "one"
each item in items
  div(id= #{items})
```

what I want is:

```
<div id="one"></div>
```

but Jade renders:

```
<div id="undefinedoneundefined"></div>
```

this is driving me crazy, I'm using Jade with Express.js.

BTW I've asked something similar but less clear, hope not to annoy anyone with my silliness.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Something like this?

```
- var items = ["one", "two", "three"]
each item in items
  div(id= item)
```